# How to identify that the string is a path to any file, using PHPcode?

Tags: php, filepath

Using PHP, How to identify that the string is a path to any file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pt.php.net/is_file

```
$path = 'string';
if(is_file($path)){
  // look, it's a file!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
is_file($filename)
is_dir($filename)
```

Will return `true` if the string points to an existing file or directory.